# How to port a MFC application to Windows Embedded Compact 7?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc, windows-embedded-compact

I'm trying to port a MFC application to windows embedded embedded 7. I added the MFC application as a sub project to the OS design I created by using platform builder in Visual Studio 2008. But i got the following errors.

Fatal Error: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\ce\atlmfc\include\atlconv.h(695) : error C2039: 'lstrlenW' : is not a member of 'ATL'
 NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\VCPackages\VcBuild.exe"' : return code '0x1'

Is there a way to solve this issue ??

After further search i found a blog stating that...

MFC and ATL are supported. However, there is currently a Microsoft bug which causes problems running such application which make use of MFC or ATL on a Windows CE 7 multi core system. To avoid problems, you need to configure the linker for Windows CE 6.
Go to "Project -> Properties"
Now choose: Configuration "Properties -> Linker -> Commandline"
If there is already a "/Subsystem" parameter delete it
Add the following string: /subsystem:windowsce,6.00

But the error persists even after following that...

Please give your suggestions to resolve this issue..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You need to install the Windows Embedded Compact 7 ATL Update for Visual Studio 2008 SP1.
It comes from Microsoft as a .MSI installer.

```
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27729
```

And to modify your project to include "Additional Include Directories" of -

```
X:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\ce7\atlmfc\include
X:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\ce7\include
```

This fixed it for me; I was building for AMC_MkII (ARMv4I)

Comment: download link may not be working anymore. it may apparently be helpful to see [here](https://community.toradex.com/t/vs2008-embedded-compact-7-specific-updates-missing/12886) (link provided from a non-answer posted as an answer).